# Error in keras tuner when try to optimize neural network using with custom layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras-tuner

I wrote architecture for anomaly detection and want to optimize my hyperparameters,

```
import keras_tuner
class GlobalAttention(Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(GlobalAttention, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        # Create a trainable weight variable for this layer.
        self.W_q = self.add_weight(name='W_q',
                                  shape=(input_shape[-1], input_shape[-1]),
                                  initializer='uniform',
                                  trainable=True)
        self.W_k = self.add_weight(name='W_k',
                                  shape=(input_shape[-1], input_shape[-1]),
                                  initializer='uniform',
                                  trainable=True)
        super(GlobalAttention, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, inputs):
        # Calculate attention scores using a dot product between inputs and W_q
        query = tf.matmul(inputs, self.W_q)
        key = tf.matmul(inputs, self.W_k)

        # Calculate attention weights using softmax
        attention_weights = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(query, key, transpose_b=True))

        # Apply attention weights to inputs
        attended_inputs = tf.matmul(attention_weights, inputs)

        return attended_inputs

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape

def build_model(hp):
  input_layer = Input(shape=(sequence_length, X_train_reshaped.shape[2]), name='classifier_input') # None, 1, 122

  lstm_layer_1 = Bidirectional(GRU(units=hp.Int('GRU_units_1', min_value=8, max_value=128, step=16), activation='tanh',return_sequences=True))(input_layer)
  attention_layer = GlobalAttention()(lstm_layer_1)

  # concatenated_features = tf.concat([attention_layer, maxpool_layer, avgpool_layer], axis=-1)
  dense_layer_1 = Dense(units=hp.Int('dense_1_units', min_value=16, max_value=128, step=16),
                        activation=hp.Choice('dense_activation_1', values = ['relu', 'tanh']))(attention_layer)
  output_layer = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax') (dense_layer_1)

  classifier = Model(input_layer, output_layer)
  classifier.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
  return classifier

tuner_test = keras_tuner.RandomSearch(
    build_model,
    objective='val_accuracy',
    max_trials=50,
    directory='new_tuning_dir',  # Change the directory
    project_name='my_attention_model',
    overwrite = True # Change the project name
)

tuner_test.search(X_train_reshaped, y_train, epochs=50, validation_data=(X_val_reshaped, y_val), batch_size=64)
```

But when I try to use it with my custom attention layer, I get error:

```
Trial 2 Complete [00h 00m 18s]

Best val_accuracy So Far: None
Total elapsed time: 00h 00m 37s

Search: Running Trial #3

Value             |Best Value So Far |Hyperparameter
8                 |88                |GRU_units_1
16                |112               |dense_1_units
tanh              |relu              |dense_activation_1

Epoch 1/50
1571/1575 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.1609 - accuracy: 0.9613

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras_tuner/src/engine/base_tuner.py", line 270, in _try_run_and_update_trial
    self._run_and_update_trial(trial, *fit_args, **fit_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras_tuner/src/engine/base_tuner.py", line 235, in _run_and_update_trial
    results = self.run_trial(trial, *fit_args, **fit_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras_tuner/src/engine/tuner.py", line 314, in run_trial
    obj_value = self._build_and_fit_model(trial, *args, **copied_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras_tuner/src/engine/tuner.py", line 233, in _build_and_fit_model
    results = self.hypermodel.fit(hp, model, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras_tuner/src/engine/hypermodel.py", line 144, in fit
    return model.fit(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras_tuner/src/engine/tuner_utils.py", line 172, in on_epoch_end
    self._save_model()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras_tuner/src/engine/tuner_utils.py", line 182, in _save_model
    self.model.save_weights(write_filepath)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-60-bf475b6b2efc> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 tuner_test.search(X_train_reshaped, y_train, epochs=50, validation_data=(X_val_reshaped, y_val), batch_size=64)

4 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras_tuner/src/engine/oracle.py in _check_consecutive_failures(self)
    384                 consecutive_failures = 0
    385             if consecutive_failures == self.max_consecutive_failed_trials:
--> 386                 raise RuntimeError(
    387                     "Number of consecutive failures exceeded the limit "
    388                     f"of {self.max_consecutive_failed_trials}.\n"

RuntimeError: Number of consecutive failures exceeded the limit of 3.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras_tuner/src/engine/base_tuner.py", line 270, in _try_run_and_update_trial
    self._run_and_update_trial(trial, *fit_args, **fit_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras_tuner/src/engine/base_tuner.py", line 235, in _run_and_update_trial
    results = self.run_trial(trial, *fit_args, **fit_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras_tuner/src/engine/tuner.py", line 314, in run_trial
    obj_value = self._build_and_fit_model(trial, *args, **copied_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras_tuner/src/engine/tuner.py", line 233, in _build_and_fit_model
    results = self.hypermodel.fit(hp, model, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras_tuner/src/engine/hypermodel.py", line 144, in fit
    return model.fit(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras_tuner/src/engine/tuner_utils.py", line 172, in on_epoch_end
    self._save_model()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras_tuner/src/engine/tuner_utils.py", line 182, in _save_model
    self.model.save_weights(write_filepath)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Without custom attention layer everything is working fine.
I tried to remove attention layer in keras tuner - worked correctly. And if i try to use it without keras tuner - worked correctly. So I think that problem with keras_tuner and custom layers.

Comment: 'Nonetype': It looks like you should check for gaps in your custom layer, prior to sending it for processing.